# Scons: What is the purpose of `FORTRAN*` variables when building Fortran?

Tags: fortran, scons

What is the purpose of the `FORTRAN*` variables in Scons? The manpage describes them as the *default settings for all versions of Fortran*. But as far as I can tell, in practice they are never used because the specific variables for the different Fortran dialects that always take precedence (`F77*`, `F90*`, `F95*`).

Is there a way to change the mapping from file extensions to Fortran dialects, so that some files get mapped to the default instead?

Comment: I must confirm your observation, they also do not work for me. I must use the F90* eventhough the manual says something different. I don't know how to change that behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking through the SCons source (particularly Tool/FortranCommon.py) it appears the that `FORTRAN` is treated as a dialect along with `F77`, `F90`, `F95` and `F03` rather than a parent to all of them.  It looks like the `FORTRAN` variant of the variables will be used for source files named with `.f`, `.for`, `.ftn`, `.fpp`, and `.FPP` though they can be overridden from the variables `FORTRANFILESUFFIXES` and `FORTRANPPFILESUFFIXES`.

The code that sets this up is:

```
def add_fortran_to_env(env):
    """Add Builders and construction variables for Fortran to an Environment."""
    try:
        FortranSuffixes = env['FORTRANFILESUFFIXES']
    except KeyError:
        FortranSuffixes = ['.f', '.for', '.ftn']

    #print "Adding %s to fortran suffixes" % FortranSuffixes
    try:
        FortranPPSuffixes = env['FORTRANPPFILESUFFIXES']
    except KeyError:
        FortranPPSuffixes = ['.fpp', '.FPP']

    DialectAddToEnv(env, "FORTRAN", FortranSuffixes,
                    FortranPPSuffixes, support_module = 1)
```

where `DialectAddToEnv` gives values to the Fortran build variables, e.g (`dialect` is the second variable passed to to the function):

```
 env['%sCOM' % dialect]     = '$%s -o $TARGET -c $%sFLAGS $_%sINCFLAGS $_FORTRANMODFLAG $SOURCES' % (dialect, dialect, dialect)
```

The code that sets up `F77`, `F90`, `F95`, etc is very similar, e.g.:

```
def add_f90_to_env(env):
    """Add Builders and construction variables for f90 to an Environment."""
    try:
        F90Suffixes = env['F90FILESUFFIXES']
    except KeyError:
        F90Suffixes = ['.f90']

    #print "Adding %s to f90 suffixes" % F90Suffixes
    try:
        F90PPSuffixes = env['F90PPFILESUFFIXES']
    except KeyError:
        F90PPSuffixes = []

    DialectAddToEnv(env, "F90", F90Suffixes, F90PPSuffixes,
                    support_module = 1)
```

There is no mechanism to fall back from one dialect to `FORTRAN`.  Each dialect (including `FORTRAN`) is separate and mapped from the file name endings, which are configurable.

Comment: How to you configure the mapping of suffixes to dialects? In scons 2.3.4 there is only one FORTRANSUFFIXES variable that contains the suffixes for *all* the dialects.